# How can the bot edit its message once the command executor's command has been edited?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
if(message.content === "hello") {
   message.channel.send("World");
}
if(message.content === "hi") {
   message.channel.send("There");
}
```

I'm trying a new feature for my bot, but I am not entirely sure how to start it. So I have the commands about this message. So what I'm trying to do is when I send `Hello` to the bot will answer `World` and if I edited the message to `hi` the bot will edit its message as well; from `World` to `There`.

discord.js version: `12.2.0`

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: @Syntle v12.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a stable solution because there isn't a proper way to edit the bot's message in this situation, so you'd have to just get the bot's last message in the channel where the message was editted and edit it.

You'd have to use the [`messageUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate) event like so:

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  if (oldMessage.content === 'hello' && newMessage.content === 'hi') {
    const messages = await newMessage.channel.messages.fetch()
    const lastMsg = messages.filter((msg) => msg.author.id === client.user.id).first()
    lastMsg.edit('there')
  }
})
```

Comment: I delete my answer, Syntle solution is a bit easier to understand than mine.
In any case, you have to use `messageUpdate` event and do some specific case with before content and after content check.

Comment: It gives me an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined`

Comment: Did the bot send a message before you edited your message?

Comment: @Syntle it did not send anything

Comment: That's the problem then, I'm not sure if you're only using the code in my answer but my answer is an extension of your code, so you still need to be able to trigger the bot to send the "world" message first before editing your message.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this. I tired it and it works.

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
        
        if (newMessage.content === "hello") {
            message.channel.send("World");
        }
        if (newMessage.content === "hi") {
            message.channel.send("There");
        }
   
})
```

You can combine thie also with deleting the previous message.